# how to culture flow from MVC Appication to web API

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, globalization

I am working in MVC Application and WebAPI .both application hosted separately.

below culture code is mentioned in Global.asax in MVC application

```
 protected void Application_AcquireRequestState(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string langCode = "";
            try
            {
                langCode = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["es-mx].Value;

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                langCode = "en-US";
            }
            CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo(langCode);
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = (ci);
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(ci.Name);             
      }
```

my mvc application know about current culture.my GET/POST request goes to web API from MVC Controller.

```
public JsonResult callWebApiAdmin(EmpViewModel objEmpModel)
        {

            object resultView = null;
            try
            {
                string url = webAPIUrl + "EmpAPI/callWebApiAdmin";

                resultView = UtilityHelper.SaveData(url, objEmpModel);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {


            }
            return Json(resultView, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

but how webAPI know which culture call from MVC Application.so that webAPI return datetime and number format according mvc application current culture.

Answer (score 0):

You can also check for the cookies in the Web API. You can implement that in a Web API action filter, or in a custom middleware component if you're usin OWIN, so that it's done automatically for all requests.

If not, you should have to store the culture in the client side and send it as a parameterto all the requests on the server side.

However, if you're using Web API, most probably you are changing the DOM elements in the client side depending on the value returned from the API. In that case you could return raw values from the Web APi and format them on the client side, for example using [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) for dates.